# Android - AVD Wipe user data isn't working

Tags: android

When I start an AVD and choose to *Wipe user data*, all of my previously input data and apps are still on the device when the emulator starts.

In Eclipse...

1. Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager
2. Select an AVD
3. Click *Start...*
4. Check *Wipe user data*
5. Click *Launch*

Once the emulator starts, my random contacts I entered are still there, my test development apps I've installed via Eclipse are still there...

If *Wipe user data* doesn't wipe this type of data, what does it do? And how do I wipe my AVD back to default settings, short of deleting it and making a new one?

Comment: I also have this "problem" and would like to understand what "wipe data" does really do in the emulator if it doesn't remove apps data nor even apps installed (it doesn't with me anyways). Too bad nobody provided an answer for it :/

Comment: At this point it seems the only way to wipe data is to just delete the AVD and make a new one.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using R12 of ADT, you may be encountering issue [18444](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18444)